# Running Excel in R and using ActiveX Controls

Tags: r, excel, vba

I have an excel application that was written in VBA that I want to run via R. I have already worked out how to open the .xlsb in R with the RDCOM package.

After opening the .xlsb I want to go through a loop that does the following:

- transfer input values from R to specific cells in Excel
- "press" an ActiveX button that opens a UI
- input values into the UI and close it
- "press" a different ActiveX button
- transfer the result to R

Now I alread wrote the code for the loop and I know how to transfer the values from R to excel and vice versa. 
I haven't figured out how to use the ActiveX elements and the UI that opens up. I don't want to have to click or type anything manually since I need to repeat that process about 700 times. 
Any hints on how something like that could work?

Thanks for any answers in advance!

Comment: Is your workbook's VBA project locked?

Comment: Show the corresponding VBA code which can be translated to R with RDCOMClient. Both run COM interface to the Excel Object Library. Do note: VBA is an add-in component and not part of Excel (see Tools / References).

Comment: The project is not locked.
I don't really want to interact with the VBA code behind the Excel Library To avoid that it would be good if I could use the Active X elements in Excel via R. Otherwise I might have to change the VBA code a little.